# What is wrong with the .add in my ArrayList?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I'm currently working on a simple game in java, representative of the DOS game [Gorillas.bas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorillas_%28video_game%29). I'm creating an arraylist to store the individual buildings do to collision checking and whatnot, but Eclipse is giving me an error no matter how I go about it. Here is what i've got for the arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> Buildings = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
Point build1 = new Point(75,30);
Rectangle building1 = new Rectangle(build1, BUILDING_WIDTH, 150);
Buildings.add(Rectangle building1);
```

The error is on the `.add()` method, it tells me that the method needs a body instead of a semicolon. What does this mean? Is eclipse not recognizing the `.add()`?

EDIT: A bit of the code around it as requested; doesn't appear to have any syntax errors.

```
public double bananaX = 85; 
public double bananaY = 292;
public double bananaDX = 1; 
public double bananaDY = 1;
public double power = 0;
public double direction = 0;
public double rise;
public double run;
Point start = new Point(0,0);
Point finish = new Point(0,0);`

ArrayList<Rectangle> buildings = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
Point build1 = new Point(75,350);
Point build2 = new Point(225, 250);
Point build3 = new Point(325, 200);
Point build4 = new Point(425, 200);
Point build5 = new Point(525, 250);
Point build6 = new Point(675, 350);
Rectangle building1 = new Rectangle(build1, BUILDING_WIDTH, 150);
buildings.add(building1);


public void power(Point start, Point finish)
{
    int power = 0;
    power = (int)start.distanceTo(finish);


}

public void direction(Point start, Point finish)
{
    double direction = 0;
    rise = (finish.y - start.y)*-1;
    run = (finish.x - start.x)*-1;
    direction = rise/run;
    bananaDX = run/10;
    bananaDY = (rise/10);
    System.out.printf("rise = %f\nrun = %f\ndirection = %f\n\n ",rise, run, direction);

}
```

Comment: You can't declare a variable inside a method call like that.  Besides, you've already declared `building` as a `Rectangle` on the previous line.  Why are you trying to do it again?

Comment: I tried `Buildings.add(building1);` first, but it wasn't working, so that was just a result of me trying anything that could possibly quiet the error.

Comment: You can't have a bare statement (`buildings.add(building1);`) outside of a method like that.  The compiler thinks you are trying to declare another variable, hence the other syntax errors.

Comment: Thank You! I put it into a constructor and all was well.
Gee, I wish I could put a check/upvote on your comment :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to have:

`Buildings.add(building1);`

Since building1 is already a Rectangle. You have already created the Rectangle object above it so you only need to use the variable itself because it is of the correct type.

Edit: You should probably also rename `Buildings` `buildings` to avoid any confusion. When you name a variable with a capital letter it looks like a type and not a variable.

Edit2: Based on the code you provided, you need to have `buildings.add(building1);` inside of a method of some sort. You should create an initialize method that gets called at the start if you want to have it added in at the beginning.

Comment: I've tried that Already, Eclipse tells me I have a Syntax error, "insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList",
as well as another , "syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)".

Comment: There may be other syntax errors in your code by the sounds of it, does it say where those other ones are? You should post the code around those as well or see if you are missing semicolon's at the end of any line

Answer (score 3):

Don't double up on Rectangle.

```
Buildings.add(building1);
```